Microsoft Visual fonts and windows not working properly
enter image description here
AS you can see in the picture, the toolbar icons are tiny.
And some of the pop up windows the texts are not entirely visible.
Its Microsoft Studio COmmunity 2017 version. No pending updates.
Any Community.
Windows and Visual studio installed any pending updates. And still it is not working.

They are entirery visible and they aren't tiny. You just need to make sure that they aren't on top of eachother. If you're working with forms you should be able to drag them and move them around. When you click on any of the labels, pop up menus, buttons and so on you can adjust their properties.
